# Keyframing a bone at a predesignated positions in the Timeline

Tags: animation, bones, keyframes

I am in a process to animate a character. I would like to know, is there any way to jump at the keyframes that have already been made for some other bones (say Bone.Ys) and now wishes to jump at those keyframes by up and down arrow for the bone (say Bone.X) on which keyframing has not been made yet.
For better understanding, I am attaching a screenshot. In which it may be seen that in Dope Sheet, there are many keyframes at various position in the timeline for some different bones (say Bone.Ys) except for Eye bone (i.e. the Bone.X). Now, I wish to put keyframes for Eye bone at the same keyframe positions of the other bones (i.e. Bone.Ys) by pressing up and down arrow and then press ‘i’ to put keyframes for Eye bone at that particular frame. Is there any way or setting to do so?
Currently, I  note the required keyframes in my notebook then type the same in timeline so that the timeline slider can move at the particular frame. This way of putting keyframes is a very tedious process and I want a better solution to jump quickly at predesignated Frames.
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: i think you could search for an add-on with that functionality...or write one on your own, shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Would you pl suggest me about any Add on or how to program? This will be a great help for me.